# Can I use older MySQL workbench with newest MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL newbie here.

- I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).
- I've successfully installed MySQL Community Server 5.7 and MySQL Community Workbench 6.3.

Unable to find these answers in the MySQL forums. I've asked this on Stack Exchange and it was suggested that I ask here instead. I've searched on Ubuntu Forum and here also but did not find an answer.
One would think they are common questions but maybe not. Additionally, I cannot find a way to ask a new question on the MySQL Forum.
I've spent a ton of time reading/researching/installing/uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL and community workbench on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) and do not want to lose the momentum I've gained. I'm actually making forward progress after a week or so of trial and error working on this up to a few hours per day.

It appears that I cannot load MySQL Community Workbench 8.0 without Linux server installed. That seems to be one of the requirements if I understood correctly.

1. Can anyone tell me if MySQL Community Workbench 6.3 will work with MySQL Community Server 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)?
   I would still like to upgrade and use MySQL community server 8.0 if I can.
2. Can I use MySQL Community Server 8.0 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit?

I've spent many hours googling it and looking on MySQL Forums but couldn't find the answer.

Thanks much. ...Rick

Answer (score 1):

In  my experience workbench 6.3 works only bad with mysql server 8.0.(it can not use the new authorisation)

The same goes for workbench 8.0 and the old Server version, some things work other not. You get also a warning when you connect.

So i have installed a Mysql 8 version and have a 6.3 in a vm, which i use to access 5.x server.

Answer (score 0):

Probably.  The language and capabilities of Workbench versus MySQL change gradually over the years.  I remember only one case of incompatibility, and it was in the *opposite* direction -- where a new Workbench version was showing a new keyword (`VISIBLE`); this messed up old MySQL/MariaDB versions.  It seemed like a dumb mistake since leaving out `VISIBLE` did no harm.

Give it a try.  If you run into trouble post the question here or on stackoverflow.com.

Similar statements can be made about versions of `phpmyadmin`.